# How to add query to display the results？ ／ TNTSearch

Tags: php, full-text-search

[TNTSearch](https://github.com/teamtnt/tntsearch)

**Searching**

First,I made index.

Then I tried the following code.

I got results as expected.

```
use TeamTNT\TNTSearch\TNTSearch;

$tnt = new TNTSearch;

$tnt->loadConfig($config);
$tnt->selectIndex("name.index");

$res = $tnt->search("This is a test search", 12);

print_r($res); //returns an array of 12 document ids that best match your query
```

---

**display the results**

I can not understand how to add query.

```
//to display the results you need an additional query
//SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id IN $res ORDER BY FIELD(id, $res);
```

---

**Draft 1**

```
$result = $tnt->query(SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id IN $res ORDER BY FIELD(id, $res));
print_r($result);
```

---

**Draft 2**

・Is it necessary to re-create the index?

```
$indexer = $tnt->createIndex('name.index');
$indexer->query('SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id IN $res ORDER BY FIELD(id, $res)');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, let me try to explain. When you execute this line

```
$res = $tnt->search("This is a test search", 12);
```

Your `$res` variable will be an array that looks something like this:

```
[
    'ids'            => [1,2,3,4,5],
    'hits'           => 5,
    'execution time' => "4ms"
];
```

The 'ids' represent the document ids that match your query.
Now it's up to you to query your database to actually get those documents with ids [1,2,3,4,5]. If you use an ORM like eloquent you would query the db like

```
$ids = implode(",", $res['ids']);
$posts = Post::whereIn('id', $res['ids'])->orderByRaw("FIELD (ID, $ids)")->get();
```

Now the `$posts` variable contains your actual posts

Comment: Thanks.I could understand.